# Post form doesn't work with routing in cake php

Tags: forms, cakephp, redirect, routes

I have implemented a pop out widow for user sign up:

here is the form popout.ctp in element folder which is called in default.ctp:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register')));
echo $this->Form->hidden('popup');
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Your Email:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Sign me Up!');
```

when I open any action in users view, the signup button works fine and page gets redirected to register action which is in user view.

while, when I'm in root, index page, which is in another view, pressing the signup button doesn't redirect to /users/register and goes to the same page.

Here is the routing:

1. `Router::connect('/users/register/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register'));`
2. `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'viewall'));`

when I remove rule number 2, signup button in events' actions works fine!

I don't understand how, this doesn't hit the first rule.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: I think you're probably not looking at "the problem" and instead some almost-unrelated aspect of it. what is the form html with and without route 2? If it doesn't change the problem isn't what you're describing. 2) _what happens_ when you submit the register form? Without details there can be no detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information, it's possible the second instance is somehow overriding the first. Another possibility is, that somehow the path to the 'action' is either invalid, or the controller assumes that the 'action' files path (i'm assuming it's '$action'.php') is relative to the path '/'.

Found this:

[cakephp routing problem, plugin routing works but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489910/cakephp-routing-problem-plugin-routing-works-but-not-others?rq=1)

Specifically:

As it turns out this happened because there was a user model and user controller in the application folder as well as the plugins controller. So the routing treated other controllers as if they weren't there.

All fixed now.

Cheers, Paul

I believe, this coincides with my initial answer.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: I could fix the problem. I had another form and forgot to add the form closing tag </form>.... so when submitting my second form, it was actually submitting my first form. :)